# Send command lines to syslog server

Tags: cisco, router, monitoring, syslog

I already can send each Linux command line to my syslog server. Now, I'd like to send each command line inserted onto my Cisco router to syslog server.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send *configuration* commands to the syslog server with the `notify syslog` command ([*Cisco IOS Configuration Fundamentals Command Reference*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/fundamentals/command/cf_command_ref/monitor_event-trace_through_Q.html#wp1955294682)):

```
archive         ! archive configuration mode
log config      ! change logger configuration mode
logging enable  ! log configuration changes
notify syslog   ! send change notifications to syslog server
```

> ### Examples
>
> The following example shows how to enable the device to send
>   notifications (in XML format) to the syslog:
>
> ```
> Device# configure terminal
> !
> Device(config)# archive
> Device(config-archive)# log config
> Device(config-archive-log-config)# notify syslog contenttype xml
> Device(config-archive-log-config)# end
> ```

You will need to use TACACS to get all commands entered.

> ## Restrictions for Configuration Change Notification and Logging
>
> - Only complete commands input in a configuration mode are logged.
> - Commands that are part of a configuration file applied with the copy    command are not logged.
>
> ## Configuration Log
>
> The Configuration Change Notification and Logging feature tracks
>   changes made to the Cisco software running configuration by
>   maintaining a configuration log. This configuration log tracks changes
>   initiated only through the CLI or HTTP. Only complete commands that
>   result in the invocation of action routines are logged. The following
>   types of entries are not logged:
>
> - Commands that result in a syntax error message
> - Partial commands that invoke the device help system
>
> For each configuration command that is executed, the following
>   information is logged:
>
> - The command that was executed
> - The configuration mode in which the command was executed
> - The name of the user that executed the command
> - The time at which the command was executed
> - A configuration change sequence number
> - Parser return codes for the command